# Transforming if-else to lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to transform a simple if-else statement that I've found myself using all over the place to a more elegant lambda expression. But I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution from what I've been reading.

The simple statement goes like:

```
if (status.getStatus() == 'A') then
  handleA();
else if (status.getStatus() == 'B') then
  handleB();
else
  handleEverythingElse();
```

I know I could use the Command pattern with a map, but I'm sure there's some Java 8 elegance that I'm missing. Could someone show me the interface & impl, as well as it's usage in the body of the code (I learn by example)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For starters you could use a `switch` statement... But why do you want a lambda anyway? If it works, don't fix it, right?

Comment: What are you expecting exactly? A usage of `Function`?

Comment: `() -> { /* your code above */ }`.

Comment: I think you are trying to overengineer your problem using some fancy new feature.  In reality I don't think that it's a good idea, the only change to make is maybe use a switch instead of an if, even then I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: fge, i already have a switch. The if-else statements are inside of the switch cases. cricket_007, yes, I was expecting to use a functional interface somehow.

Comment: If you are trying to see how something like this looks in a functional style in Java, look at Optional.

Comment: Eh, so that is _inside a switch_. Time to rethink your approach, maybe?

Comment: What is your use case?  What does this snippet do within the code?

Comment: puhlen, inside of a stream I'm getting the "status" for a list of objects. Based on that status I either go to the database to get a new ID for the object, or I reuse an existing object's ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I hadn't fully explained my problem, but my colleague proposed another solution that I really like. He suggested I make the if-else block a java.util.Supplier, and invoke it in the Entity class where I need it.

So my code went from this block of logic sprinkled everywhere:

```
public class ServiceImpl {
  ...
  if (entity.getStatus) == 'A' then
    finalStatus = handleA();
  else if (entity.getStatus() == 'B') then
    finalStatus = handleB();
  else
    finalStatus = handleEverythingElse();
  ...
}
```

To this nicely compacted form:

```
public class ServiceImpl {
  finalStatus = entity.getFinalStatus(this::handleStatus);

  public int handleStatus() {
    return dao.getStatus();
  }
}
```

With the implementation in my Entity class:

```
public class Entity {
  public int handleStatus(Supplier<Integer> s) {
    int finalStatus;
    if (status) == 'A' then
      finalStatus = handleA();
    else if (status() == 'B') then
      finalStatus = handleB();
    else
      finalStatus = supplier.get();
    return status;
  }
}
```

I hope this make sense...

Answer (score 2):

If/else or even switch are not the "good OO design" answer. Neither are lambdas. Retrieving the status from somewhere, to make then a decision based on that - that is procedural programming; not OO.

You see, what you actually have in front of you - is a **state machine**. You have **different states**; and the point is: if your "thing" is in state A; then you want to do something ( invoke handleA() ). If your are in state B; you want to do something too (  like invoke handleB() ).

So, what you actually have is:

```
abstract class State {
  abstract void doIt();
...

StateA extends State {
  @Override
  void doIt() { handleA(); }
```

So, from the client side, you just call doIt() on same object of class State.

Thus: if you are really interested in improving your code base, learn how to use polymorphism to get rid of your if/else/switch statements.

You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79&index=4) to get an idea what I am talking about.

Comment: Nice answer to what looks to be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. I remember my own face when I first was told about something like that in my own code. To then figure: creating good OO designs especially around this kind of problems can be so rewarding ... that I can't resist to share such ideas as often as possible.